# Fact or Hoax : Unconventional method of saving human life from stroke?

Tags: medications, first-aid

When someone gets a stroke their capillaries in the brainare gradually tearing. Usually, we bring the patient to the nearesthospital for immediate treatment.

On the other hand.

> There's one unconventional method of saving human life from stroke. It is the
>   method of a Chinese Professor who said that this method is 100%
>   efficient. He added that if a family member got hit by stroke,
>   just be calm. Regardless of where the victim is, do not move them,
>   because if you move the patient, capillaries will burst and bleeding
>   in the brain will occur.
>  Here are the steps on how a needle can
>   save a stroke patient's life:
>
> 1. Hold the needle over a fire for a few seconds in order to sterelized it, and then use it to make a small stab wounds on all 10
>      fingers.
> 2. There is no specific acupuncture. The stab wounds should be only a few millimeters from the nail.
> 3. The wounds are made so the blood can flow.
> 4. If there is no bleeding you should apply some pressure in order to cause bleeding.
> 5. When all ten fingers start bleeding you should wait for a several minutes and you will see that the patient will come back to life!
> 6. If the victim's mouth is distorted, massage their ears until they become red by improving the blood flow.
> 7. Then you need to use the needle and poke in each ear's soft part in order to make two drops of blood drop (from each ear). A few minutes
>      later, the patient's mouth would no longer be distorted.
>
> Wait until the patient becomes conscious and their movement went back
>   to normal without any unusual symptoms. Afterwhich, bring them to the
>   hospital for further treatment.

It seem the unconventional method like a hoax for me. Actually it is FACT or HOAX ?

Comment: Sheer nonsense.

Comment: Whenever someone says something is 100% efficient (or effective) it is untrue (well most of the time :P)  It is a sign someone is over selling something. And if they are having to over sell to get you to buy (in), well that just smells fishy to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Grandmother died of a ischemic stroke (TIA followed by blockage) after weaning herself off of blood thinners because she didn't **"need the medicine"**.

Huge issue with his advice - the large majority of strokes are due to a clot or another form of vessel blockage. The rest caused by a hemorrhage (you'll have the worst headache of your life) while bleeding profusely internally.

> That advice literally makes me mad ***(not at you)*** -- but whoever wrote it.
>    
> *Physiologically it makes no sense.*  In most cases that would kill someone.

---

**Below is Advice According to the MayoClinic.org**

---

### **Symptoms**

---

Watch for these signs and symptoms if you think you or someone else may be having a stroke. Note when your signs and symptoms begin, because the length of time they have been present may guide your treatment decisions:

- **Trouble with speaking and understanding.** You may experience confusion. You may slur your words or have difficulty understanding speech.
- **Paralysis or numbness of the face, arm or leg.** You may develop sudden numbness, weakness or paralysis in your face, arm or leg, especially on one side of your body. Try to raise both your arms over your head at the same time. If one arm begins to fall, you may be having a stroke. Similarly, one side of your mouth may droop when you try to smile.
- **Trouble with seeing in one or both eyes.** You may suddenly have blurred or blackened vision in one or both eyes, or you may see double.
  Headache. A sudden, severe headache, which may be accompanied by vomiting, dizziness or altered consciousness, may indicate you're having a stroke.
  Trouble with walking. You may stumble or experience sudden dizziness, loss of balance or loss of coordination.

---

### **When to see a doctor**

**Seek immediate medical attention** if you notice any signs or symptoms of a stroke, even if they seem to fluctuate or disappear.

*Think "FAST" and do the following:*

- Face. Ask the person to smile. Does one side of the face droop?
- Arms. Ask the person to raise both arms. Does one arm drift downward?
  Or is one arm unable to raise up?
- Speech. Ask the person to repeat a simple phrase. Is his or her
  speech slurred or strange?
- Time. If you observe any of these signs, call 911 immediately.

Call 911 or your local emergency number right away. Don't wait to see if symptoms go away. Every minute counts. The longer a stroke goes untreated, the greater the potential for brain damage and disability.

If you're with someone you suspect is having a stroke, watch the person carefully while waiting for emergency assistance.

---

### **Causes**

A stroke occurs when the blood supply to your brain is interrupted or reduced. This deprives your brain of oxygen and nutrients, which can cause your brain cells to die.

A stroke may be caused by a blocked artery (ischemic stroke) or the leaking or bursting of a blood vessel (hemorrhagic stroke). Some people may experience only a temporary disruption of blood flow to their brain (transient ischemic attack, or TIA).

> **Ischemic Stroke**

About 85 percent of strokes are ischemic strokes. Ischemic strokes occur when the arteries to your brain become narrowed or blocked, causing severely reduced blood flow (ischemia). The most common ischemic strokes include:

- **Thrombotic stroke.** A thrombotic stroke occurs when a blood clot (thrombus) forms in one of the arteries that supply blood to your
  brain. A clot may be caused by fatty deposits (plaque) that build up
  in arteries and cause reduced blood flow (atherosclerosis) or other
  artery conditions.
- **Embolic stroke.** An embolic stroke occurs when a    blood clot or other debris forms away from your brain — commonly in    your heart —
  and is swept through your bloodstream to lodge in    narrower brain
  arteries. This type of blood clot is called an    embolus.

> **Hemorrhagic stroke**

Hemorrhagic stroke occurs when a blood vessel in your brain leaks or
   ruptures. Brain hemorrhages can result from many conditions that
   affect your blood vessels, including uncontrolled high blood pressure
   (hypertension), overtreatment with anticoagulants and weak spots in
   your blood vessel walls (aneurysms).

A less common cause of hemorrhage is the rupture of an abnormal
   tangle of thin-walled blood vessels (arteriovenous malformation)
   present at birth. Types of hemorrhagic stroke include:
 - **Intracerebral hemorrhage.** In an intracerebral hemorrhage, a blood vessel in the brain bursts and spills into the surrounding brain
   tissue, damaging brain cells. Brain cells beyond the leak are
   deprived of blood and also damaged.

High blood pressure, trauma, vascular malformations, use of blood-thinning medications and other conditions may cause an intracerebral hemorrhage.

- **Subarachnoid hemorrhage.** In a subarachnoid hemorrhage, an artery on or near the surface of your brain bursts and spills into the space
  between the surface of your brain and your skull. This bleeding is
  often signaled by a sudden, severe headache.

  A subarachnoid hemorrhage is commonly caused by the bursting of a
  small sack-shaped or berry-shaped outpouching on an artery known as
  an aneurysm. After the hemorrhage, the blood vessels in your brain
  may widen and narrow erratically (vasospasm), causing brain cell
  damage by further limiting blood flow.

> **Transient ischemic attack (TIA)**

A transient ischemic attack (TIA) — also known as a ministroke — is a brief period of symptoms similar to those you'd have in a stroke. A temporary decrease in blood supply to part of your brain causes TIAs, which often last less than five minutes.

Like an ischemic stroke, a TIA occurs when a clot or debris blocks blood flow to part of your brain. A TIA doesn't leave lasting symptoms because the blockage is temporary.

Seek emergency care even if your symptoms seem to clear up. Having a TIA puts you at greater risk of having a full-blown stroke, causing permanent damage later. If you've had a TIA, it means there's likely a partially blocked or narrowed artery leading to your brain or a clot source in the heart.

It's not possible to tell if you're having a stroke or a TIA based only on your symptoms. Up to half of people whose symptoms appear to go away actually have had a stroke causing brain damage.

Comment: Hey! Congrats on breaking the first sound barrier here (1000). Would you mind adding the links to your sources into the answer?